# Create zip file without headers

Tags: go, zip

I’ve two zip’s ,and I use a zip command to check the difference between the two zip,
    `diff -y (unzip -l old.zip | psub) (unzip -l new.zip | psub)`
I need them to be exactly the same

First created in **old tool** which look like this and it’s OK

```
 Length      Date    Time    Name                
---------  ---------- -----   ----              
      158         02-18-2018 12:26   META/MANI.MF        
      153         02-18-2018 12:26   META/mt.yaml        
  3956032         02-18-2018 12:26   ui/data.zip                    
---------                     -------       ---------                    
  3956343                     3 files
```

This is the zip with the **new tool** which look different

```
  Length      Date    Time    Name              
---------  ---------- -----   ----               
|           0  02-18-2018 20:37           ./
|           0  02-18-2018 20:37           META/
|         150  02-18-2018 20:37           META/MANI.MF
>         178  02-18-2018 20:37           META/mt.yaml
>           0  02-18-2018 20:37           ui/
>     3980703  02-18-2018 20:37           ui/data.zip
```

if we look at the ui folder (zip of the new tool) you see that in the new there is two entries

> ```
>   ui/
>   ui/data.zip
> ```

And I need only the second as in the old tool, the file structure should be identical

The logic to build it is like this

> 1. during the program process I’ve folder which is called `ui’
> 2. I zip it with the function Zipit(see code below) on the level so I’ve it like this
>          root
>            - ui
>            - ui.zip
> 3. then I remove the `ui` becouse I need just the zip and it contain a lot of files that not needed after the zip process
> 4. create new empty folder `ui`  os.MkdirAll(path, os.ModePerm)
> 5. Mmove the zip inside the new `ui` folder - os.Rename(path+".zip", path+"/"+"data.zip")

What am I doing wrong here ? I need the new structue will be inside the zip exactly the same

```
func Zipit(params ...string) error {


    zipfile, err := os.Create(params[1])
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer zipfile.Close()

    archive := zip.NewWriter(zipfile)
    defer archive.Close()

    info, err := os.Stat(params[0])
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }

    var baseDir string
    if info.IsDir(); len(params) > 2 {
        baseDir = params[2]
    } else {
        baseDir = filepath.Base(params[0])

    }

    filepath.Walk(params[0], func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        header, err := zip.FileInfoHeader(info)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if baseDir != "" {
            header.Name = filepath.Join(strings.TrimPrefix(path, params[0]))
        }

        if info.IsDir() {
            header.Name += "/"
        } else {
            header.Method = zip.Deflate
        }

        writer, err := archive.CreateHeader(header)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if info.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }

        file, err := os.Open(path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer file.Close()
        _, err = io.Copy(writer, file)
        return err
    })

    return err
}


to see the difference between the zip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to skip adding directories to the zip file header, every time you see a directory in the `filepath.Walk` callback just skip it:

```
filepath.Walk(params[0], func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // I moved this check to the beginning of the callback.
    if info.IsDir() {
        return nil
    }

    header, err := zip.FileInfoHeader(info)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if baseDir != "" {
        header.Name = filepath.Join(strings.TrimPrefix(path, params[0]))
    }

    header.Method = zip.Deflate

    writer, err := archive.CreateHeader(header)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer file.Close()
    _, err = io.Copy(writer, file)
    return err
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I've check it and I get the same structure as before i.e. the `ui` folder is still exist when checking the zip's , do you have another idea?

Comment: @Ninawatcher hm, are you sure about that? Just checked on my computer and the zip didn't have directories (I checked using `unzip -l`).

Comment: Can you please provide the all code that you use , maybe I miss something?